# How to remove all files from a directory except a few ones?

Tags: linux, shell, delete-file, rm

I have a directory structure something like:

```
/var/www/html/pictures/media0/01/test_01.jpg
/var/www/html/pictures/media0/01/test_02.jpg
/var/www/html/pictures/media0/01/test_03.jpg
/var/www/html/pictures/media0/01/test_04.jpg
/var/www/html/pictures/media0/01/test_05.jpg
```

I would like to remove all files from `01` except `test_03.jpg` and `test_05.jpg` by using a linux command, maybe `rm`?

Any ideas?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/138282/how-to-delete-files-on-the-command-line-with-regular-expressions 

This link should help I think..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to move the files you want to keep somewhere else, then delete the rest and move them back.

If this is for a script and you need something fancier I can write something using `find` that will do it. Let me know.

Comment: that's fine, i actually know the name and full path of all files that i want to keep, from a loop, but maybe u are wright, it will be easier to copy them

Comment: @Patrioticcow Not copy - move. As long as it's on the same file system the move command is basically instant. Writing something with `find` is not hard though.

Comment: This is actually very smart idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
rm !(path_to_file/test_0{3,5}.jpg)
```

This will exclude all files except **test_03.jpg** and **test_05.jpg**

Comment: That's not exactly very general purpose.

Comment: He said the directory structure was just an example.

Comment: thanks for reply. unfortunately that doesn't work for me, that expression removes those files, i only know the ones that i want to keep

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s extglob
echo !(/var/www/html/pictures/media0/test_0[3,5].jpg)
```

If the output is the files you want to delete replace "echo" with "rm" and run it again.